# How to use font-style and font-family with styled-components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have set the font-family in GlobalStyle. However I want to use another font-family and additional another font-style in one component. It somehow does not work to set it like below.

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    ...
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <BrowserRouter>
        ...
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

and

```
const Text = styled.p`
  font-style: "italic";
  font-family: "Arial";
  ...
`;
```

The Result is the following

```
<p font-style="italic" font-family="Arial" class="sc-gtsrHT imMzcY">
```

But actually the font is still Montserrat and the style normal.
How can I overwrite global style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. `font-style: italic;`

```
...
const Text = styled.p`
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Arial";
`;

...
return (
  ...
    <Text>Hello World<Text>
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the "p" tag instead of the "Text" tag you created, you need to use `<Text> <Text/>` instead `<p> </p>`.